# Trigonometric involving bearings

Tags: trigonometry

A figure shows sport A,B,and C on level ground.B is due east of A while C is due north of A.D is the top of a tower,cd. Given that AC=500m,and the angle of elevation of D from A and B are 30° and 25° respectively. Calculate the height  CD at the Tower to 2 decimal place and hence calculate the distance BC to 2 decimal place.calculate the bearing of c from B

Comment: Am waiting for the answers

Comment: Hint:you can use tangent function to find CD.  Then use tangent again to find BC.  Then use tangent again to find the bearing.